# AJAX Updating Javascript Variable from PHP page?

Tags: php, ajax, variables

I am not a developer so this is new to me, but I am a long time sys admin so please forgive me if I am asking stupid questions!

Basically, I have a PHP script that parses some XML and echo's a single number formatted to 1 dp.

I am using some Javascript Wijmo widgets, in particular a dial that takes it input from a javascript variable. Lets say "resultvalue".

I want to populate "result value" every 5 seconds with the results of my php script that exists as /xmlparse.php. The wijmo widget apparently responds dynamically to a changing variable so this will produce a dial with a moving needle without having to refresh the whole page.

All I need to achieve is getting this javascript variable to update every 5 secs.

I am already doing something similar with AJAX on a html page by just populating a DIV with the results of /xmlparse.php and it works great using the set interval command.

But how can I get my javascript variable updating every 5 secs with the result of that script?

An example would be a great help!

[Code Here](http://one-sightsolutions.com/new.txt)

Regards
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url:'/xmlparse.php'
    }).done(function(response) {
        resultvalue=response;
    });
},5000);
```

You'll probably need to parse the result. Perhaps xmlparse should format it with json_encode so your ajax request could grab it as an object.

**Edit:** 
Looking at your source, I see that the radial gauge doesn't actually monitor the resultvalue variable to detect when it's changed. You'll have to update it yourself. In this case:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url:'/xmlparse.php'
        }).done(function(response) {
            resultvalue=response;
            $("#gauge").wijradialgauge({value:resultvalue});
        });
    },5000);
```

Comment: Hi there @amenadiel , thanks for your help but that's not populating the variable.

If I declare it and set it before your code then the output in the dial shows what I set it to, but not what your code is supposed to do.

    var resultvalue = 0
    window.setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({ 
    url:'/xmlparse.php'
    }).done(function(response) {
    resultvalue=response;
    });
    },5000);'

Comment: Depending on where you declare it, the resultvalue variable will have different scopes. Make sure you declare it as a global variable. For example, not prepending *var* when you set its value to zero.

Comment: I have attached some of the code to the question. I am still unable to make your xml get code work. The output value is whatever I set it to, not what is in the php script.

Comment: I am still confused. Here is a link to the code, would you be able to take a look at it and see what is going on?

The end result needs to be that the wijmo widget that reads its value from resultValue is supposed to dynamically update (Its a guage with a moving needle). We have got the resultValue variable updating but it just isn't being read by the widget.

http://one-sightsolutions.com/new.txt

Tom

Comment: See my edit. I thought the widget was actually binded to the variable, but it isn't.

Comment: You sir, are a god amongst men!

Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable and set it as value returned from `xmlparse.php`;

```
var resultValue;
// load at page load first
$(document).ready(function() {
  updatevalue();     
}); 

setInterval("updatevalue()", 5000);

function updatevalue(){
    $.get("xmlparse.php", function(response) {
      resultValue = response;
    })
}
```

This is for test

```
setInterval("test()", 4000);

function test() {
  console.log("Result is: " + resultValue);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the variable is still undefined after the code. And if I set the resultvalue before, thats what is returned after. Not the result of my php script.

Comment: How did you check? Have you seen that ajax request successfully sent?

Comment: Sorry, like I said, I am new to this. What I done was put a document write outside of the function, after your code that prints the contents of the variable.

It didn't contain the contents of the php script which should be a number e.g. 4.2

I have a feeling this is to do with variable scopes?

Comment: It outputs undefined. Because, the function runs after 5 seconds. See my updated answer for test. Every 4 seconds, you will se resultValue in console

Comment: @tomstephens89 an upvote and approval would be appreciated :)

Comment: No problem, but one more question. Is it possible to load the php script result into the java variable on page load just once before the interval loading function starts? So I don't have to wait 5 seconds to see a value...

Comment: Thanks again, but unfortunately I am still confused. Here is a link to the code, would you be able to take a look at it and see what is going on?

The end result needs to be that the wijmo widget that reads its value from resultValue is supposed to dynamically update (Its a guage with a moving needle). We have got the resultValue variable updating but it just isn't being read by the widget.

http://one-sightsolutions.com/new.txt

Tom